# Twitter status update - not working

Tags: php, twitter

Hey, did twitter change something in their API?

This no longer works for me:
http://morethanseven.net/2007/01/20/posting-to-twitter-using-php.html

Anyone knows if it's something with my machine or just an API update from twitter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That script uses [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), but Twitter [discontinued support](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html) for basic authentication at the end of August. There's more information about OAuth in Twitter's [OAuth FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq).

Answer (score 2):

1. Twitter stopped using Basic Authentication (ended 31 August 2010) and moved to [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). Use OAuth.
2. Twitter API address has changed. The address to the Twitter API has also changed. View this [doc](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) to see how the status update is applied (*http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml* has changed to *http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml*).
3. Your link provided, that documentation was written in 2007, January 20. The **new** [Twitter API doc](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) describes what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter only supports [oauth](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/06/switching-to-oauth.html). You should use a library that supports oauth.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me,
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/youraccountname.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4